# CAShapeLayer can't use rect path?

Tags: ios, calayer

I draw a dash border

```swift
let centerView = UIView()
centerView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 80, height: 50)
        
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        
shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [3, 2]
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.5
shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(
  roundedRect: centerView.bounds,
  cornerRadius: 22
).cgPath
        
view.addSubview(centerView)
centerView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

When I tap `Debug View Hierarchy`

Runtime issue:

> A `CAShapeLayer` is used with a path that's a rect, a rounded-rect, or an ellipse. Instead, use an appropriately transformed plain CALayer with `cornerRadius` set.

How to fix it?

Comment: I can only produce this as an "Optimization opportunity", not as an issue. I believe what you are doing is OK. I would personally go with `UIView` subclass and override `draw` method to achieve this. But the reasons for that are that it is easier to control a view with constraints and everything.

Answer (score -1):

Use the layer's shadowPath instead of path
like this:

```
shapeLayer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(
  roundedRect: centerView.bounds,
  cornerRadius: 22
).cgPath
```

Comment: Why are you setting the shadowPath?